# Java swing set font color with HTML tag but cyan and magenta color don't work

Tags: java, html, swing, colors, jlabel

[image]

Hello I'm trying to change font color in JLabel with html tag like this,
`<font color="+fontColor+">`
every other color such as red, orange, blue, fuchsia, gray, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, silver, teal, green, yellow, white, and black but cyan and magenta do not.

Does anyone know why those two special colors don't work in java?

Thank you!

Comment: Share your code on how you are setting.

Comment: Do you think it is possible for us to know what is wrong with your code without looking at **_your code_**?

Comment: After reading your question, I sent a Pull Request to the OpenJDK project.

Comment: It's the forge for Java Implementation (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/9825). This is really easy to implement, the proposal is a simple extension of existing code, I also made other propositions to improve it. If acceped, Java Swing HTML will take in charge all CSS Level 4 named colors and then the cyan and magenta (https://www.w3.org/TR/2022/CR-css-color-4-20220705/#named-colors).

Comment: This issue is now referenced and waiting its review. Fill free to comment at https://github.com/scientificware/jdk/issues/12.

Comment: This issue is in review and needs an update of its java documentation. Next step CSR.

Comment: I posted another PR to update hexadecimal notation support, allowing #RGB #RGBA #RRGGBB and #RRGGBBAA https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/10317. It's waiting a review after a new implementation proposition.

Comment: @Moungsung Thanks for your question. I'm going to post another and last PR about rgb() and rgba() functions.

Comment: Named colors (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/9825), hexadecimal notations (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/10317) and RGB/RGBA function (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/15262) are now in the same PR : https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/9825. Release in JDK 22 ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Swing HTML renderer is quite old.  It conforms to HTML 3.2 and CSS 1.0.

The `color` attribute of `<font>` is parsed using the non-public [CSS.stringToColor](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.java#L1393) method, which only recognizes 17 color names: Black, Silver, Gray, White, Maroon, Red, Purple, Fuchsia, Green, Lime, Olive, Yellow, Navy, Blue, Teal, Aqua, and Orange.

For what it’s worth, JavaFX is a more modern UI library which has a [WebView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) component that uses WebKit for rendering, and thus has much more up-to-date HTML and CSS support.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same issue, try to use hex `#00FFFF` instead of `cyan`.

As Mr. [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) commented, Swing's HTML support (which is a subset of HTML 3.2), and CSS is so poor, it would be safest to only use hex or RGB values for colors.

Comment: Delete this and add it as a comment to your question. This is not an answer.

Comment: @hfontanez I disagree. I suspected that using the color names rather than the hex or RGB value of the color was the problem purely by reading the title. But it *does* need improvement and expansion to be a *good* answer. OP, please paraphrase (or copy/paste) further details from my comment and include them as an [edit] to the answer. You might also add that since Swing's HTML support (which is a *subset* of HTML 3.2), and CSS is so poor, it would be safest to only use hex or RGB values for colors.

Comment: @AndrewThompson "_But it does need improvement and expansion to be a good answer_" This is what I meant, I also confused the "!" for a "?" because it is too damn early and I haven't had my morning coffee. LOL

Comment: @hfontanez *"haven't had my morning coffee"* Ah, Pre1CoD (Pre 1st Coffee of Day). I understand now. I'm hopeless before I have been caffeine enhanced.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Could you please push to reopen this question ? As explained in my last comment, this thread helped to solve this problem and two others if PRs are accepted .

Comment: @hfontanez please could also push to reopen this question ?